# How can I increment the Key of a TreeMap when I want to insert the same key?

Tags: java, key, treemap

I have a TreeMap where there is a list of id (the Key) and more data that would be the values. So, when I insert a key and value to the TreeMap, it goes well when the key isn´t in the TreeMap. The problem is when it's in there. I have to update al the Key from the new one, so the new Key will be in his position, and the one that was before in that position will be in the next one.

Example:
**Key**: 1 **Value**: a
**Key**: 2 **Value**: b
**Key**: 3 **Value**: c
**Key**: 4 **Value**: d
**Key**: 5 **Value**: e

*Insert Key 3, value f:*
**Key**: 1 **Value**: a
**Key**: 2 **Value**: b
**Key**: 3 **Value**: f
**Key**: 4 **Value**: c
**Key**: 5 **Value**: d
**Key**: 6 **Value**: e

Comment: Are your keys just like the ones above, simple and eventually all will be sequential starting at 1?   Otherwise a List won't work.

Answer (score 1):

The `Map` behaves exactly as it should: Every key in a `Map` is unique. Means: **No** duplicate keys. If you `put` an entry with a key that already exists, it will override the old entry.

If you just want an incrementing list of items, use a `List`:

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
list.add("a");
list.add("b");
list.add("c");
list.add("d");
list.add("e");
```

print it:

```
for(int i=0; i<list.size(); i++) {
  System.out.println("Key: " + (i+1) + " Value: " + list.get(i));
}
```

When you now want to insert something in the middle, just use `add` with index:

```
list.add(2, "f");
```

result of print:

```
Key: 1 Value: a
Key: 2 Value: b
Key: 3 Value: f
Key: 4 Value: c
Key: 5 Value: d
Key: 6 Value: e
```

Answer (score 0):

You haven't specified how the map is to be used nor whether your keys are more complex and random than specified.  So I offer a different possibility.

- first, create some data.

```
int[] keys = { 1,5,7, 10,12,15,40,40,50,18,10,8,
        10, 3, 4, 5, 10, 12, 14, 19 };
String[] values = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz".split("");
```

- start off with a `TreeMap<Integer, List<String>>`
- Then store them as follows:

```
NavigableMap<Integer, List<String>> map = new TreeMap<>();


for(int i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
    map.computeIfAbsent(keys[i], v-> new ArrayList<>()).add(values[i]);
}

map.entrySet().forEach(System.out::println);
```

Prints (each element is in a list associated with its original ID)

```
1=[a]
3=[n]
4=[o]
5=[b, p]
7=[c]
8=[l]
10=[d, k, m, q]
12=[e, r]
14=[s]
15=[f]
18=[j]
19=[t]
40=[g, h]
50=[i]
```

- Now create another map to provide a one to one mapping of key to element.

```
int start = map.firstKey();
for(int key : map.keySet()) {
    start = key < start ? start : key;
    for (String v : map.get(key)) {
        map2.put(start++, v);
    }
    
    
}
System.out.println(map2);
```

Prints

```
{1=a, 3=n, 4=o, 5=b, 6=p, 7=c, 8=l, 10=d, 11=k, 12=m, 13=q, 14=e,
 15=r, 16=s, 17=f, 18=j, 19=t, 40=g, 41=h, 50=i}
```

The point being if your `ids` are not sequential starting at 0, you can't use a list as lists can't have gaps between the indices.  Otherwise a list is fine.

Answer (score 0):

Using for loop for of adding same items from a list.
If the Map has already added that keys(Strings), you replace the old value(Integer) with getting it and incrementing it by 1

```
> List<String> list = new ArrayList<>(List.of("A", "B", "B", "C", "D",
> "E", "E", "E", "F", "G", "H"));
>     Map<String, Integer> letters = new HashMap<>();
>     for (String s : list) {
>         if (letters.containsKey(s)) {
>             letters.put(s, letters.get(s) + 1);
>         } else {
>             letters.put(s, 1);
>         }
```

Answer (score 0):

For the simple use case as given in your example you could try something like below, assuming your keys are sequential :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Map<Integer, String> map = new TreeMap<>();
    map.put(1, "a");
    map.put(2, "b");
    map.put(3, "c");
    map.put(4, "d");
    map.put(5, "e");

    System.out.println("Before inserting new key value pair:");
    System.out.println(map);
    
    int newKey = 3;
    String newValue = "f";

    if (map.containsKey(newKey)) {
        map.keySet().stream()
                .filter(e -> e >= newKey)
                .collect(Collectors.toCollection(ArrayDeque::new))
                .descendingIterator()
                .forEachRemaining(e -> {
                    map.put(e + 1, map.get(e));
                });
    }
    
    map.put(newKey, newValue);
    System.out.println("\nAfter inserting new key value pair:");
    System.out.println(map);
}
```